# In Google Analytics, how do I filter sessions by device platform?

Tags: google-analytics

When I open the "User Explorer" section in Google Analytics and open the details of a specific user, I can see their session's Device Platform and Device Category, just like this:

[image: User Report details screen with highlighted relevant info]

However, where as I can create segments and get insights reports on the Device Category (Mobile, Tablet or Desktop), I cannot figure out a way to create a segment or see a report of the number of users per Device Platform (app or web).

Is there a way to filter all users or all sessions based on this "Device Platform" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this data is available through the [reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_datasource), and also available to be used in segments. E.g.:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, the name "data source" didn't match the label from the other screen "device platform", and that's why I was confused. I googled quite a bit before asking the question but wasn't finding anything. Cheers :)